# Why use Vertex Buffer Objects for dynamic objects?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

Not sure what the DX parlance is for these, but I'm sure they have a similar notion.

As far as I'm aware the advantage of VBO's is that they allocate memory that's directly available by the GPU. We can then upload data to this buffer, and keep it there for an extended number of frames, preventing all the overhead of uploading the data every frame. Additionally, we're able to alter this data on a per-datum basis, if we choose to.

Therefore, I can see the advantage of using VBO's for static geo, but I don't see any benefit at all for dynamic objects - since you pretty much have to update all the data every frame anyways?

Comment: The corresponding concept in D3D is [`DEFAULT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476259(v=vs.85).aspx) resource usage, and your observation concerning the appropriateness of this kind of memory for dynamic vertex data is correct.  In D3D, `DYNAMIC` would be preferred. Did someone tell you otherwise?

Comment: What are you comparing VBO's to? I'm guessing immediate mode OpenGL (`glBegin/End`)?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Vertex arrays

Comment: @MooseBoys No, someone didn't tell me different, but most places I see assume VBO's, claiming they are superior. Also, the GL analysis tooling on iOS complain about not using VBO's.

Comment: In DirectX 11 it's the difference between creating a Vertex Buffer with ``D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC`` vs ``D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT``. Typically ``D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC`` will prefer to allocate the resource from memory in the PCIe aperture so that both the GPU & CPU can get to it.  ``D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT`` generally prefers to allocate from VRAM and there's a copy from a system RAM to the VRAM to initialize or update it which is slower for the CPU to access, but faster for the GPU to use over and over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods of updating buffers in OpenGL. If you have dynamic data, you can simply reinitialize the buffer storage every frame with the new data (eg. with [glBufferData](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferData.xhtml)). You can also use client vertex buffer pointers, in compatibility contexts. However, these methods can cause 'churn' in the memory allocation of the driver. The new data storage essentially has to sit in system memory until the GPU driver handles it, and it's not possible to get feedback on this process.

In later OpenGL versions (4.4, and via extensions in earlier versions), some functionality was introduced to try and reduce the overhead of updating dynamic buffers, allowing for GPU allocated memory to be written without direct driver synchronization. This essentially requires that you have the [glBufferStorage](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferStorage.xhtml) and [glMapBufferRange](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) functionality available. You create the buffer storage with the `GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT`, and then map it with `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` (you may require other flags, depending on whether you are reading and/or writing the data). However, this technique also requires that you use GPU fencing to ensure you are not overwriting the data as the GPU is reading it. Using this method makes updating VBOs much more efficient than reinitializing the data store, or using client buffers.

There is a good presentation on [GDC Vault](http://gdcvault.com/play/1020791) about this technique (skip to the DynamicStreaming heading).

Comment: Hmm. Seems this isn't available w/o extensions on ES, disappointing. Can you explain "However, these methods can cause 'churn' in the memory allocation of the driver. The new data storage essentially has to sit in system memory until the GPU driver handles it, and it's not possible to get feedback on this process."? I am not sure what you mean. Is the data always copied to driver memory before GPU can handle it? Does the latter method avoid this?

Comment: When you give new data to a buffer with either client buffers or glBuffer[Sub]Data, the input buffer can be immediately destroyed. This indicates that it is copied elsewhere during the call. However, in general, these sorts of writes to buffers need to be scheduled (for the same reason that the glMapBufferRange writes need to be fenced), so you will have multiple copies of mesh data in memory at a time - likely some of them in driver system memory. Once it is 'safe', the driver system memory copy gets transferred to GPU memory. With the latter method, there is only ever one buffer.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, by creating dynamic vertex buffer, you are giving graphic adapter driver a hint to place vertex buffer in memory which fast for CPU to write but also reasonably fast for GPU to read it. Driver usually will manage it to minimize GPU stall by giving non-overlapping memory area so that CPU can write while GPU read other memory area.

If you do not give hint, it is assume a static resource so it will be placed in memory which fast for GPU to read/write but very slow for CPU to write.

Comment: Is this always true? What about for say, mobile devices that use a unified memory model?

Comment: For unified memory architecture, GPU and CPU both have fast read/write access to system memory.

Comment: For integrated GPUs (AMD APU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Accelerated_Processing_Unit), they share same die and memory space with CPU. It gives them advantage because they can communicate without limitation by PCI-e bus. However their performance usually not as good as discrete GPUs which have faster memory on board

Comment: So is VBO's useless for unified? Even for separate, does the driver actually have access to different types of memory to save the data copy?

Comment: If VBO is useless, they will not become OpenGL core feature. VBO is just an abstraction, so you can use it same way even the actual data vertex data is in VRAM or System RAM.